# iOS keyboard hangs when changing input mode from dictation to handwriting very frequently

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

there.

**A short foreword.**
I have a game for iOS where player can enter their name. For input I use standard iOS keyboard. Game uses OpenGL ES 2.0 as it's render engine.

Everything works fine except that when I add a Chinese handwriting keyboard on my iPad, switch to it when trying to enter player name and then I start very rapidly change input mode from dictation to handwriting and back. So I'm just sitting there and tap randomly on dictation button when handwriting keyboard is active and 'Done' button, when Siri is active.

After a while keyboard hangs in somewhere in between dictation and handwriting mode. It doesn't respond to 'Done' button. Closing application and reopening will help, but it's not an option.

On the screenshot ([Screenshot of the keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m65ZV.jpg)) you can see that Siri mode kind of dominates the keyboard input mode, but the rectangle in the bottom is the part of the handwriting input mode.

So, **the question is**: can I do anything about this problem or I've got no influence over the iOS keyboard?

**P.S. Further details:**
For input I use hidden (out of the screen) UITextField. When I need to show the keyboard, I make this textField the first responder and the keyboard pops up.

There was an internal error message:
"requesting caretRectForPosition: with a position beyond the NSTextStorage (-1)"
which I fixed by making a custom class based on the UITextField and redefining this method like this:

```
- (CGRect)caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition *)position
{
    CGRect rect = [super caretRectForPosition:position];

    if (rect.origin.x == INFINITY || rect.origin.y == INFINITY) {
        rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    return rect;
}
```

It did help to eliminate that internal bug, but didn't help with the keyboard hang.