# Requesting caretRectForPosition: while the NSTextStorage has outstanding changes

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uitextview

I've been recently getting the error:

```
requesting caretRectForPosition: while the NSTextStorage has oustanding changes {x, x}
```

* "Oustanding" is literally what it says, and is not my typo.

This is being called when I am iterating through the `NSTextStorage` of a subclass of `NSTextView` with the `enumerateAttribute()` method and manipulating the `NSTextAttachment`s in the text view after every change in the text view.

```
func manipulateText() {
    let text = customTextView.textStorage
    text.enumerateAttribute(NSAttachmentAttributeName, inRange: NSMakeRange(0, text.length), options: NSAttributedStringEnumerationOptions(rawValue: 0)) {
    //
    }
}

extension ThisViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
        manipulateText()
    }
}
```

Questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845747/ios-keyboard-hangs-when-changing-input-mode-from-dictation-to-handwriting-very-f) seem to be online, but I have yet to find any occurrences of this and seems to be relevant to iOS 9 only.

This only happens when using a physical keyboard on iPad.

Comment: Happens for me with or without a physical keyboard in 9.2.

Comment: @SamSoffes Do you happen to override any of the caret-related methods?

Comment: Nope. I am doing some complicated stuff though. Haven't spent time trying to simplify to figure it out.

Comment: @NaotoIda did you solve this? If so, pelase answer you question.

Answer (score 6):

This happens if you call `caretRectForPosition` (or any method that calls that like `firstRectForRange`) while the text storage has edits.

I was able to prevent these logs by deferring some stuff until after `endEditing` is called in the NSTextStorage and `dispatch_async` to the main queue to do my work. There aren't any visible UI flashes or anything as a result of the async.

There has to be a better way to solve this, but this is all I could figure out.

Comment: any recent updates on this issue? I'm getting the same glaring typo'd error message

Comment: <bump> I have a custom NSTextStorage that works fine with standard UITextView, but demonstrates this issue when I use it with my custom UITextView subclass.  I overrode caretRectForPosition: and found that editedMask == 0 and editedRange == (NSNotFound,0) just before the error occurs.  How can I figure out what is causing this issue? (I need to use my custom UITextView class in production, but can test with standard class).  All of my beginEditing and endEditing calls are paired.  Any ideas appreciated!  Thanks!!

Comment: @FletcherT.Penney I don't remember this specific issue, but I commonly do something similar so maybe this will help. When there are edits or other things in the NSTextStorage I want to react to, I set a variable (something like `needsUpdate`) to true. In `processEditing`, I call `super` and then if that flag is set, I'll do some work. Maybe try that?

Comment: Figured it out last night -- more of a "forehead slap" moment.  The issue was a leftover macOS line of code that added a second layoutmanager.  That was somehow causing an issue on iOS, and explained why it worked ok with a stock UITextView.   (And yes, I do something similar in processEditing myself -- it has worked great so far!)  Thanks for responding!!!  Also explains why my diagnostics weren't finding anything useful -- the sttextstorage itself was ok.